# Azure queue check number of messages

Tags: azure, message-queue, azure-queues

For purposes of our integration checking, I want to count the number of messages on an Azure queue. The method looks like this:

```
internal void VerifyMessagesOnQueue(string queueNameKey, int expectedNumberOfMessages)
{
    var azureStorageConnectionKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageConnectionKey"];
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureStorageConnectionKey);
    var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[queueNameKey]);
    var messages = queue.PeekMessages(int.MaxValue);
    messages.Count().Should().Be(expectedNumberOfMessages);
}
```

Right now I'm using `var messages = queue.PeekMessages(int.MaxValue);` to try to get all the messages on a queue. It returns an HTML repsonse 400. I have tried `var messages = queue.PeekMessages(expectedNumberOfMessages);`, but when `expectedNumberOfMessages` is 0, I also get an HTML response 400.

How can I reliably check the number of messages on an Azure queue without disrupting it (this is why I was using `.PeekMessage`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to count the number of messages on an Azure queue

I suggest you could try the following code to achieve your goal. I have created a console project to test.

StorageConnectionString in App.config:

```html
<appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=×××;AccountKey=×××" />
</appSettings>
```

Code in Program.cs:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Queue_Name = "myqueue";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
            CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();           
            CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(Queue_Name);
            queue.FetchAttributes();
            var count=queue.ApproximateMessageCount;
            Console.WriteLine("message number in queue:"+count);
        }
```

The Result about queue count:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Janley Zhang's answer is correct. To get approximate messages count in a queue, you will need to fetch queue's attribute. Adding a new answer to clarify the following:

> Right now I'm using var messages = queue.PeekMessages(int.MaxValue);
>   to try to get all the messages on a queue. It returns an HTML repsonse
>   400. I have tried var messages = queue.PeekMessages(expectedNumberOfMessages);, but when
>   expectedNumberOfMessages is 0, I also get an HTML response 400.

Essentially `PeekMessages` is used to retrieve the messages from the top of the queue without altering the retrieved messages visibility.

Maximum messages that can be fetched from a queue in a single request is 32 and the minimum is 1. Please check this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/peek-messages) (URI Parameters section ) for more details.

In both of scenarios, you're specifying a count that is out of allowed range (1 - 32) and this is why you're getting the `400` error back from the queue.